# textcomp \textarrow not found in font family ppl TS1 encoding

Tags: fonts

Using `\textuparrow` I get the following error:

```
Package textcomp Error: Symbol \textuparrow not provided 
by font family ppl in TS1 encoding. Default family used instead.
```

However, the arrows are drawn correctly, but with another font. How to get rid of the error message since it blocks latexml to run through?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
\textuparrow
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also: [textcomp vs TS1 font encoding](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/issues/74)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Redefine the command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\renewcommand{\textuparrow}{$\uparrow$}

\begin{document}
\textuparrow
\end{document}
```

You can change the error into a warning by loading the package with the `warn` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[warn]{textcomp}

\begin{document}
\textuparrow
\end{document}
```

The output is the same, you only receive the warning

```
Package textcomp Warning: Symbol \textuparrow not provided by
(textcomp)                font family ppl in TS1 encoding.
(textcomp)                Default family used instead on input line 8.
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04 worked for me. See https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/issues/74#issuecomment-590005846.