# How to adjust table column parameters in this tabularx correctly?

Tags: tabularx

I am trying to adjust the column parameters but I cannot find a good combination (`l`/`X`/`p{.1\linewidth}`). 
Adding there `X` makes the column extremely small in the example code of Fig. 1, which I do not understand. Therefore, I have no `X` there at the moment. 
Code which output fails with the last columns, in Fig. 2 without `X`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309253/13173
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[warn]{textcomp}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\resizebox{.5\textheight}{!}{
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| l |  p{.27\linewidth} |  p{.27\linewidth} |  p{.27\linewidth} | p{.2\linewidth} |} %
\hline 
\textbf{Feature} & \textbf{Cytotoxic edema} 
         & \textbf{Vasogenic edema} 
         & \textbf{Interstitial edema} 
         & \textbf{Osmotic edema} \\ \hline 
Composition & i/c, acc. of water and Na+
        & e/c, ultrafiltrate of plasma
        & CSF
        & V(e/c) $>$ V(i/c) \\ \hline
Location of edema & Gray-white matter 
          & White - -
          & Periventricular white - - 
          & White - - \\ \hline
V(E/c fluid) & \textdownarrow 
         & \textuparrow 
         & \textuparrow 
         & \textuparrow \\ \hline
Etiology       & DM, hypothermia, ... 
           & Tumors, trauma, ...
           & Hydrocephalus 
           & Hemodialysis, hypertensive crisis, ...\\ \hline
Response to therapy & Yes/No (diuretics transiently eff.)
            & Yes (corticosteroids)
            & Yes (diuretics transiently eff.)
            & Yes/No \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\caption{Types of brain edema.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Fig. 1 Output without `X`, 
Fig. 2 Output with one `X`

[image]
[image]

Comment: In order for `tabularx` to work, you need *at least one `X`-column*. Your example code shows you're not using any.

Comment: @Werner Adding there `X` makes the column extremely small, which I do not understand. Therefore, I have no `X` there at the moment. - - I added an output with one `X`.

Comment: That's because there's no available room for an `X`-column once the other columns take up `\textwidth`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines. I would also set the column types ragged-right rather than fully justified. Finally, don't use a `table` environment -- just place the "caption" in the argument of `\frametitle`. Observe that the code below *by design* does not employ `\resizebox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[warn]{textcomp}

\usepackage{ragged2e,tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\hyphenation{cortico-steroids diu-ret-ics}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Types of brain edema}

\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}
    >{\hsize=0.86\hsize}Y 
    *{4}{>{\hsize=1.035\hsize}Y} @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Feature} & \textbf{Cytotoxic edema} 
         & \textbf{Vasogenic edema} 
         & \textbf{Interstitial edema} 
         & \textbf{Osmotic edema} \\ 
\midrule 
Composition & i/c, acc. of water and Na+
        & e/c, ultrafiltrate of plasma
        & CSF
        & V(e/c) > V(i/c) \\ 
\addlinespace
Location of edema & Gray-white matter 
          & White - -
          & Periventricular white - - 
          & White - - \\ 
\addlinespace
V(E/c fluid) & \textdownarrow 
         & \textuparrow 
         & \textuparrow 
         & \textuparrow \\ 
\addlinespace
Etiology       & DM, hypothermia, \dots 
           & Tumors, trauma, \dots
           & Hydrocephalus 
           & Hemodialysis, hypertensive crisis, \dots\\ \addlinespace
Response to therapy & Yes/No (diuretics transiently eff.)
            & Yes (corticosteroids)
            & Yes (diuretics transiently eff.)
            & Yes/No \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am scared about using manually fontsize adjustment directly. I like the resizebox much more.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영, I have opposite scare ... resize box is desperate action of last resort without control on result which usually/many time gives ugly result as from aesthetic point of view as from aspect of readability ...

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 _never_ apply `\resizebox` to tables!

Comment: You are both so correct! - - This output is so much superior.

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
  \begin{tabularx}{1.5\textwidth}{| l | X | X | X | X |} %
   ....
```

[image]

Comment: Confirmed, works! Thank you! The main thing is to change the first field to 1.5 and then you can use Xs freely. Why?

Comment: The columns will be too small if you use only `\textwidth`.